# ElasticSearch : special characters while searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index where I am searching on a field whose analyzer is 'english'. I had a problem with queries with special characters, and I found this :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Is there a clean way to create an escaped version of the query in java ? Lucenes query parser does not cover all the characters which ES needs to escape.

Comment: Can you give an example of a query that causes issues?

Comment: heres a snippet : 

"query": {
 "filtered": {
  "query": {
   "query_string": {
    "default_field": "INDEXED_FIELD",
    "query": "1/2' shoe"
   }
  }
 }
}
I need to escape the / and the ' here. It

Comment: Ok, though the apostrophe `'` is not a reserved character.

Comment: Is it possible that your users write full-fledge Lucene queries like `1/2' shoe && "brown jacket"`? If yes, that would be a problem because `/` needs to be escaped, while `&&` doesn't. Have you considered using [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) instead?

Comment: Any feedback to my above comment?

Comment: Hey Val, apologize for the delay ! I used match instead and things went good. I had to escape the '/' but thats all i had to escape.